# How to remove row from Mysql Query result on foreach depending value of the same array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I am using the following code to display array information

```
$select = new Class;
$stmt = $select->selecttimemonthlyall();
foreach($stmt as $row){

echo $row['name'];
echo $row['time'];

}
```

Where `$stmt` is the execution of the query PDO object

Question here is how I can limit the results depending the the $row['time']
for example

I have a variable `$key = 30;`

then I need to put a condition like this

```
if(($key - $row['time']) < 30) { 
    unset($row[current]); 
}
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't call your variable `$stmt` unless it's a `PDOStatement` object. If it's just a regular array, name it more appropriately.

Comment: Do you want to remove from the array or just not display in your loop?

Comment: It is PDOStatment object.

Comment: Also, why not use your database to limit the results instead of fetching unnecessary results and then removing them?

Comment: Remove or not display both will work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't iterate over a PDOStatement object

Comment: @Mike I'm pretty sure you can.

Comment: @Barmar Gap in my knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just not display in your loop according to your condition

```
$key = 30;
foreach($stmt as $row){
    if(($key - $row['time']) >= $key) { 
       echo $row['name'];
       echo $row['time'];
    }
}
```

I would rather limit returned rows directly in the query instead of filtering them in the loop with lack of resources

Answer (score 1):

You can unset the element of the array with the key of the foreach:

```
$stmt = $select->selecttimemonthlyall();

foreach($stmt as $k => $row) {
  if(($key - $row['time']) < 30) {
    unset($smt[$k]); 
  }
}
```